# Attaching a fragment to an inflated view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am attaching a fragment to an inflated view.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.view, MyFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
```

The R.id.view is in the inflated view. This works when I go forward in the flow. But if I press back I get a view not found error

```
 No view found for id 0x7f0700b5 (com.package:id/view) for fragment AFrag_F{4141ccb8 #1 id=0x7f0700b5}
```

I found that if I manually remove the fragment before it is stopped then back press will work. But this noticeably slows down the app.  Is there a better way of doing this? Sadly I have to use an inflated view and can't change that. Is it possible to have the backstack ignore my transaction? I tried

```
  disallowAddToBackStack();
```

which didn't work

Comment: Is `R.id.view` a `fragment`?

Comment: it is a frame layout where i place my fragment

Comment: `R.id.view` doesn't seem to be an `inflated view`, you're getting it with the id.

Comment: it is i am doing something like this View myView = view.inflate(R.layout.view); mainFragmentHolder.addView(myView); and R.id.view is contained in myView.

Comment: But you're not using `myView`.

Comment: I am. I have a fragment view that has myView dynamically added. I didn't post the code for adding myView

Comment: Could post that? And why do you want to use a `inflated view` as the `frame`?

Comment: it just your standard inflate view with .addView() I am locked into this implementation by bad design choices from others unfortunately